# Laravel 9 pass model object into view

Tags: laravel, view

I am trying to pass a model object into view and use it in JS, but I can't make it work. It looks broken and throws a syntax error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'` if I just use the variable.

I tried using `compact()` but this does not work aswell `compact(): Argument #1 must be string or array of strings, App\Models\Quiz given`

Here is how I return the view with the object:

```
$result = Quiz::where('id', $quiz_id)->first();

if (!$result['active'] || $result['hidden_by_admin']) {
    return abort(404);
}
$result['classic_questions'] = ClassicQuestion::where('quiz_id', $quiz_id)->with('classic_answers')->get();
$result['quiz_tags'] = QuizHasTags::where('quizzes_id', $quiz_id)->with('quiz_tag')->get();

return view('play_quiz')->with('quiz', $result);
```

Here is how I want to access it in blade.php:

```
<script>
    const quiz = {{ $quiz }};
    console_log(quiz);
</script>
```

Comment: `compact()` works if the variable name is `$quiz`, `->with(compact('quiz'))` would be `->with(['quiz' => $quiz])`

Comment: Your issue is probably `{{ $quiz }}`; that just echo's out the string representation of your `Quiz` record. You probably need something like `const quiz = JSON.parse("{{ $quiz->toJson() }})"`, or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assign your data into the window global object which will make it
> available everywhere and you can access it from your JS file:

```
<ul>
    @foreach ($quiz as $quiz_data)
        <li> {{ $quiz_data }} </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.data = {!! json_encode($quiz) !!};
</script>
<script src="...."></script>
```

// trying to access the model $data from the view.

```
$(function() {
    var values = window.data;
    alert(values);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also send data to view like this:
In  controller:

```
 return view('play_quiz', $result);
```

In view

```
foreach($quiz_tags as quiz){
//code
}
```